# How to connect to mi MongoDB compass?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

Can't connect to mi MongoDB compass, have you seen this message?

```
mongo db 2280064:error:10000438:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR:..\..\third_party\boringssl\src\ssl\tls_record.cc:592:SSL alert number 80
```

I tried updating to the lastes version but it did not work.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add current IP adress, on mongo atlas.

After doing that it will work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first  go to your mangodb atlas and enable add current ip address

[see image below to eanble add current ip address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEufL.png)
then go back to your mangodb compas and select connect.